# Nesting web components from dart code

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have multiple nested web components to represent a grid. I need to compose these in dart code. 
I have a function to create the web component as recommended by the dart docs :

```dart
void addWebComponent(WebComponent component,String tagName,WebComponent parent) { 
    component.host = (new Element.html("<${tagName}></${tagName}>"));        
    var lifecycleCaller = new ComponentItem(component)
    ..create();
    parent.append(component.host);
    lifecycleCaller.insert();
    return;
}
```

Each web component contains a template like so :

```dart
  <template>
      <div class="grid">
         <div class="large-12 columns" >                    
            <content></content>
         </div>
       </div>          
  </template>
```

My assumption is that calling  **parent.append(component.host);**  will add the injected web component html into the CONTENT element. It doesn't. 
This is what I'm expecting as a result :

```dart
<x-grid>
      <div class="grid">
         <div class="large-12 columns">
             <x-row> 
                  <div class="row">...</div>           
             </x-row>
         </div>
       </div>          
</x-grid>
```

This is what I get :

```dart
 <x-grid>
      <div class="grid">
         <div class="large-12 columns"> 
                 **[Content should be here!]**               
         </div>
       </div>    
         **[ CONTENT ENDS UP HERE]**
         <x-row> 
                  <div class="row">...</div>           
             </x-row>

</x-grid>
```

My guess is that from dart code you can't add to the web component's content via parent.append(component.host). Is there some other function or steps required to make this work?
It's killing me.

Comment: What's being passed as "String tagName"? Additionally is 'parent' already inserted into the DOM before the addComponent function is called?

Comment: the tagNames are "x-grid" when called from main,"x-row" when called from gridComponent,"x-column" when called from RowComponent.

Comment: I'll have to test more to see if the parent is inserted into the DOM before addComponent is called. I'm under the impression that lifecycleCaller.insert() adds the component to the Dom. If that's the case then no the parent is not added to the dom until after the component is added to the parent. The docs are weak concerning dynamically creating web components.

Comment: Your "host" should be the HtmlElement that your element extends (ie. DivElement). Your 'component' should be the WebComponent subclass you created for it (ie: new XRow();). I tried similar test case but couldn't reproduce your results, my elements were nested as you expected. But I had a much smaller example than I'm sure your code is and probably have some significant differences.

Comment: I changed the host to be a plain Div but I get the same result. None of the nested components are inserted into the content area. 
This is also the case for nesting components in html : 
<x-grid><x-row></x-row></x-grid>   
The damn x-row is appended as the last child of the parent component instead of being inserted into <content></content> area of the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add to parent:

```dart
List<WebComponent> items = toObservable([]);
```

Change:

```dart
parent.append(component.host);
```

To:

```dart
parent.items.add(component);
```

Then modify the HTML to be like:

```html
<template>
  <div class="grid">
     <div class="large-12 columns" template iterate="item in items">                    
        {{ new SafeHtml.unsafe(item.host.innerHtml) }}
     </div>
  </div>          
</template>
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting an error : HTML had 0 top level elements but 1 expected.

Comment: This is a pain. For some reason my M5 release is not hitting any debugger breakpoints making it very frustrating to figure this out lol.

Comment: That error is thrown because `SafeHTML.unsafe()` expects exactly one top-level HTML element. I'm not sure why it has 0, it sounds like `host` isn't properly initialized yet..

Comment: Hmm. It works when I turn off useShadowDom! Question, Does this affect the way Web Components work? It's a little confusing. I used outerHtml instead of innerHtml so my component <div is="x-row"> is injected into the DOM.

Comment: Also if I do it your way I lose the option of declaring the webcomponents in html.

Comment: I like your solution but I need the component to work the same if declared in html or built in code. I need to be able to insert my nested templates into the <content></content> of a parent component at "runtime". To the web component source code!

Comment: Ok, I got it. Turns out the solution is easier to find when you understand how things work. lol.

Comment: @logan Please edit my answer and fix/edit it so that others can find your solution too. :)

Comment: I replaced your answer because my solution ended up being completely different. Thank you for helping out!